# How do you replicate the EE {date_heading} tag pair in Craft?

Tags: date

I'm wondering how I would replicate the ExpressionEngine [`date_heading`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#date-heading) tag pair in Craft?

```
{date_heading}  {entry_date format="%Y %m %d"}  {/date_heading}
```

> The date heading can be used to show a heading at certain intervals.
>   The interval can be set to show hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, or
>   yearly.

Comment: Could you clarify the ultimate goal here? Is it to show entries grouped by dates?

Comment: Yep... that's exactly what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Group:**

Take a look at Craft's custom [group filter](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group). Your example could look like this:

```twig
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').find() %}
{% set allEntriesByDay = allEntries | group('postDate') %}

{% for day, entriesInDay in allEntriesByDay %}
    <h1>{{ day }}</h1>

    {% for entry in entriesInDay %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

.

**Conditionals:**

You could also save the last entries date and use conditionals:

```twig
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog') %}
{% set last_date = '' %}

{% for entry in allEntries %}
    {% if last_date < entry.date %}
        This entry is the first of a new day
    {% endif %}

    {% set last_date = entry.date %}

    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question... but how do I reformat the {{ day }} variable in your first example? If I do something like:
    {{ day|date("D") }}
It changes every instance to the same date.

Comment: @JesseBennett-Chamberlain You're right, my mistake. I accidentally added .day to postDate which means only the numerical value was passed. I edited the answer, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I like **conditionals** approach by Victor. Here's the slightly modified version for Craft 2.6:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog') %}
{% set last_date = '' %}

{% for entry in allEntries %}
    {% if last_date != entry.postDate|date('Ymd') %}

        This entry is the first of a new day
    {% endif %}

    {% set last_date = entry.postDate|date('Ymd') %}

    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

The key (apart from .date being .postDate) is that entry.postDate will render a *formatted* value like 2017-02-23, however the *evaluated* value of entry.postDate will be the underlying timestamp, which includes hours/minutes/seconds. This means two entries from the same day may have a postDate that outputs 2017-02-23, but their underlying timestamps will likely have different h/m/s, making comparisons unreliable. Being explicit with postDate output (e.g. 'Ymd', or 20170223) solves the issue.